# Appending Multiple values to arrays in a struct?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I feel like I am attempting this at the completely wrong angle...

So far, i have my parsed JSON that is stored in 10 different arrays:

```
Alamofire.request(FULL_API).responseJSON { (response) in
        print("AddCoinModel: Full Api = \(FULL_API)")
        if response.result.error == nil {
            guard let data = response.data else { return }
            if let json = JSON(data: data).array {
                for item in json {

                    let id = item["id"].stringValue
                    self.coinImageIdStringArray.append("https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/\(id).png")

                    let name = item["name"].stringValue
                    self.coinFullNameArray.append(name)

                    let symbol = item["symbol"].stringValue
                    self.coinSymbolArray.append(symbol)

                    let price = item["price_\(self.API_FIAT.lowercased())"].numberValue
                    self.coinPriceArray.append(Double(price))

                    let priceBtc = item["price_btc"].numberValue
                    self.coinPriceInBitcoinArray.append(Double(priceBtc))

                    let volume = item["24h_volume_\(self.API_FIAT.lowercased())"].numberValue
                    self.coinVolume24hArray.append(Double(volume))

                    let marketCap = item["market_cap_\(self.API_FIAT.lowercased())"].numberValue
                    self.coinMarketCapArray.append(Double(marketCap))

                    let percent1h = item["percent_change_1h"].numberValue
                    self.coinPercentChange1hArray.append(Double(percent1h))

                    let percent24h = item["percent_change_24h"].numberValue
                    self.coinPercentChange24hArray.append(Double(percent24h))

                    let percent7d = item["percent_change_7d"].numberValue
                    self.coinPercentChange7dArray.append(Double(percent7d))


                    var coinApiStructArrays = CoinStructure.init(idForImageString: id, fullName: name, symbol: symbol, price: Double(price), priceInBitcoin: Double(priceBtc), volume24h: Double(volume), marketCap: Double(marketCap), pctChange1h: Double(percent1h), pctChange24h: Double(percent24h), pctChange7d: Double(percent7d))
                    print("aaaaa:\(coinApiStructArrays)")
                    self.coinapistruct.append(coinApiStructArrays)
                    print("bbbbb:\(self.coinapistruct)")

                }
                completion(true)
            }
        } else {
            completion(false)
            debugPrint("AddCoinModel: getCoinInfoFunc: \(response.result.error as Any)")
        }
    }
```

So far I have had to reference each array whenever I want to pass the data into a tableview/collectionview.

I thought there must be a simpler way, so i attempted to create a struct for the json so i could enter all the data into one line of code and call on it in the future without having to type 10 lines of code for 10 arrays.

Struct:

```
struct CoinStructure {
    public private(set) var idForImageString: String!
    public private(set) var fullName: String!
    public private(set) var symbol: String!
    public private(set) var price: Double!
    public private(set) var priceInBitcoin: Double!
    public private(set) var volume24h: Double!
    public private(set) var marketCap: Double!
    public private(set) var pctChange1h: Double!
    public private(set) var pctChange24h: Double!
    public private(set) var pctChange7d: Double!
}
```

I did use the 'init' function:

```
init(id: String){ idForImageString = id ...}
```

And then attempted to create a variable of the struct and set each value of the json equal to it

```
 var array = CoinStructure.init(id: id ... etc)
```

Eventually when i printed the first 5 results of the api i got:

```
CoinStructure(idForImageString: bitcoin, fullName: Bitcoin, symbol: BTC, price: 4385.61, priceInBitcoin: 1.0, volume24h: 2766630000.0, marketCap: 72565890651.0, pctChange1h: 0.38, pctChange24h: 3.15, pctChange7d: -4.16)
```

(next 4 are essentailly the same but different values..)

Ok, so far this is ok, but what i need is something along the lines of:

```
CoinStructure(idForImageString: [bitcoin, litecoin], fullName: [Bitcoin, Litecoin], symbol: [BTC, LTC]...)
```

So then when i populate the tableview/collectionview i can call indexPath.row for lets say the first index in the array and pull 'litecoin' 'Litecoin' and 'LTC' out of the arrays.

I feel like im going about this completely wrong and surly there must be a simple way to do this instead of making a mess like I have?

Many thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: What's `API_FIAT`? On a side note, I suggest you use DecimalNumber to represent fractional currency values, as it doesn't accrue the precision errors that `Float`/`Double` do

Comment: Im using the coinmarketcap.com api, so API_FIAT is just the currency symbol for the api e.g. USD, MXN, IDR. I used this so when a user changes currency i refresh my data and pull the converted currency values from the api.

Comment: I see. You should give it a better name, then. Perhaps `userFiatCurrencySymbol`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of such a struct is for a single `CoinStructure` instance to model a single coin type. You're trying to model multiple types of coins, so you should make multiple instances of your `CoinStructure`.

On a side note, there's no need to put `Structure` in the name. We can see that it's a structure. However, the rest of the name, the `Coin` part, is wrong. This structure doesn't model a coin, it models a cryptocurrency.

Additionally, the mutability of all members, as well them all being implicitly unwrapped optionals, is a really big red flag.

Here is how I would model this:

```
import Foundation

import Foundation

struct CryptoCurrency {
    public let idForImageString: String // FIXME: <--- what is this thing? It's really unclear
    public let fullName: String
    public let symbol: String

    public let price: Decimal
    public let priceInBitcoin: Decimal
    public let volume24h: Decimal
    public let marketCap: Decimal

    public let pctChange1h: Decimal
    public let pctChange24h: Decimal
    public let pctChange7d: Decimal

    init(
        idForImageString: String,
        fullName: String,
        symbol: String,
        price: Decimal,
        priceInBitcoin: Decimal,
        volume24h: Decimal,
        marketCap: Decimal,
        pctChange1h: Decimal,
        pctChange24h: Decimal,
        pctChange7d: Decimal
    ) {
        self.idForImageString = idForImageString
        self.fullName = fullName
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.price = price
        self.priceInBitcoin = priceInBitcoin
        self.volume24h = volume24h
        self.marketCap = marketCap
        self.pctChange1h = pctChange1h
        self.pctChange24h = pctChange24h
        self.pctChange7d = pctChange7d
    }

    init?(fromJSON: JSON) {
        guard let idForImageString = json["id"].stringValue,
            let fullName = json["name"].stringValue,
            let symbol = json["symbol"].stringValue,
            let price = json["price_\(self.API_FIAT.lowercased())"].number?.decimalValue,
            let priceInBitcoin = json["price_btc"].number?.decimalValue,
            let volume24h = json["24h_volume_\(self.API_FIAT.lowercased())"].number?.decimalValue,
            let marketCap = json["market_cap_\(self.API_FIAT.lowercased())"].number?.decimalValue,
            let pctChange1h = json["percent_change_1h"].number?.decimalValue,
            let pctChange24h = json["percent_change_24h"].number?.decimalValue,
            let pctChange7d = json["percent_change_7h"].number?.decimalValue else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(
            idForImageString: idForImageString,
            fullName: fullName,
            symbol: symbol,
            price: price,
            priceInBitcoin: priceInBitcoin,
            volume24h: volume24h,
            marketCap: marketCap,
            pctChange1h: pctChange1h,
            pctChange24h: pctChange24h,
            pctChange7d: pctChange7d
        )
    }
} 


Alamofire.request(FULL_API).responseJSON { (response) in
    print("AddCoinModel: Full Api = \(FULL_API)")
    guard response.result.error == nil,
        let data = response.data,
        let jsonArray = JSON(data: data).array else {
        completion(false)
        debugPrint("AddCoinModel: getCoinInfoFunc: \(response.result.error as Any)")
        return
    }

    self.cryptocurrencies = jsonArray.map { json in
        guard let cryptocurrency = CryptoCurrency(fromJSON: json) else {
            //FIXME: Handle the error case appropraitely
            fatalError("This JSON doesn't represent a valid CryptoCurrency, and my author didn't handle his errors properly!'")
        }
        return cryptocurrency
    }

    print(self.cryptocurrencies)
    completion(true)
}
```

Here's an example of what `self.cryptocurrencies` would look like:

```
let cryptocurrencies = [
    CoinStructure(
        idForImageString: bitcoin,  // FIXME: <--- what is this thing? It's really unclear
        fullName: "Bitcoin",
        symbol: "BTC"
        ...
    ),
    CoinStructure(
        idForImageString: litecoin,  // FIXME: <--- what is this thing? It's really unclear
        fullName: "Litecoin",
        symbol: "LTC"
        ...
    ),
]
```

Comment: Hi, when I try to use the code I get an error saying 'use of unresolved identifier 'json' '. I have tried it with and without swiftyjson, still the same error. Not sure what im missing?

Comment: Also, the 'idForImageString' is the url of the image for each coin in string verson. later i convert that into an image using alamofire. Just noticed I made a mistake in my original comment, it shouden't say 'bitcoin', rather a url to the image.

Comment: @Jeremy As you can see, i renamed `json` to `jsonArray`, and `item` to `json`

Comment: @Jeremy So if it's a `URL`, why is called an `id`? And why is it a `String`, and not a `URL`?

Comment: Ahh i see! Thanks :)  . I made it a string at the very start of the project and never really gave it a second thought.. I called it id as from the api i got the coins id (e.g. 'bitcoin' or 'litecoin'), and then interpolated that into the URL for the image which ended in .../bitcoin.png.